# I want to put a text box in range

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a layer by onclick event.

But as you can see, The part over the top is cut out and can not be seen.
    Can you make the speech bubble automatically adjust its position?
    In any the direction, what should I do to make the content look perfect?

```js
function tooltip(thechosenone) {
  $('.toolTip').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
      $(this).show(200);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.toolTip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  top: -10px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f0ce93;
  white-space: pre-line;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  border: 2px dotted #208033;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 170%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="tooltip('ss')">1234</div>
<div id="ss" class='toolTip'>
  <a href='#' target='_blank'>1234</a>
</div>
```

Comment: remove that top:-10px from your tooltip class it will come fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function tooltip(thechosenone) {
     $('.toolTip').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(200);               
          }
       });
 // this will automatically adjust when -ve value is specified.
 if( parseInt($(".toolTip").css("top")) <= -1 ) {
     $(".toolTip").css({'top':'0%'});
  }
 }
```

```css
  .toolTip {
      position:absolute;
      width:300px;
      top:-50px;
      display:none;
      background-color: #f0ce93;
      white-space:pre-line; 
      border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
      -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
      border: 2px dotted #208033;
      padding : 5px 10px;
      font-size:17px;
      line-height:170%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="tooltip('ss')">1234</div>
<div id="ss" class='toolTip'>
<a href='#' target='_blank'>1234</a>
</div>
```

Edited, previous code, code added for auto correction.

Comment: well, I did it on purpose. I want "automatically"

Comment: You can add script to handle it.

Comment: I could not find a perfect case. There was a similar thing. http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/examples/monet/monet.html

Comment: The standard is unknown, but the direction of the speech balloon is different.

Comment: Edited the previous answer, Code for auto correction added.